# Compare file names (minus extension) in different directories and copy/move if the same name with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to compare filenames (minus extensions) between two directories and if there are matches, copy (or move [tbd]) the files from one of two to a 3rd directory.  i.e.

Dir_A has a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg, d.jpg, e.jpg, f.jpg

Dir_B has a.pdf, c.pdf, d.pdf, f.pdf

results would be

Dir_C gets a.jpg, c.jpg, d.jpg,f.jpg

I've been able to accomplish this with a batch file, but want to learn how to through AHK.

The batch file is:

```
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
pushd D:\temp
For /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('dir /a-d /b *.jpg') DO (
    IF EXIST "D:\temp\comp\%%~nI.pdf" move "%%~I" "D:\temp\new\" 
)
```

After a lot of looking, finding *similar* posts and attempting to interpolate, I think I'm close but am obviously missing something. I'm hoping someone would please shed light on this for me.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

SFolder:="D:\temp\"         ;Source folder
CFolder:="D:\temp\comp"     ;Compare folder
DestDir:="D:\temp\new"      ;where to move files

Loop,
 {
    Loop, %SFolder%*.jpg        ;look for all jpg files
    JpgName = %A_LoopFileName%  ;save the file names to var 
    Loop, %CFolder%*.pdf        ;look for all pdf files
    PdfName = %A_LoopFileName%  ;save the file names to var

    JpgCompare:=Trim(JpgName,".jpg")    ;remove the files .ext
    PdfCompare:=Trim(PdfName,".pdf")    ;remove the files .ext

    If JpgCompare = %PdfCompare%    ;if there are matching file names (minus .ext)
                                    ;in both directories
    {
        FileMove, %JpgName%, %DestDir%  ;move the file.jpg to the "new" directory
    }
    Else
    {}
 }
Esc::
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SplitPath](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplitPath.htm) to store the jpg file name without its path, dot and extension in a variable (name_no_ext) and check for the existence of a pdf file with the same name in the other directory using [FileExist()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileExist.htm):

```
SFolder:="D:\temp\"         ;Source folder
CFolder:="D:\temp\comp"     ;Compare folder
DestDir:="D:\temp\new"      ;where to move files

Loop Files, %SFolder%*.jpg        ;look for all jpg files
{
    SplitPath, A_LoopFileName,,,, name_no_ext
    If FileExist(CFolder . "\" . name_no_ext . .pdf)
        FileMove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %DestDir%  ;move the file.jpg to the "new" directory
}
```